# Invalid signature. Expected signature base string - OAuth1.0 Yelp API

Tags: ios, objective-c, yelp, oauth-1.0a

I am using yelp V2 API in my app.I am getting below response for requesting restaurant and food detail in any particular area. I tried almost all solution of stack overflow and everywhere else I got. But still no progress. Can anyone help me please?

Error :

> {"error": {"text": "Signature was invalid", "id": "INVALID_SIGNATURE",
>   "description": "Invalid signature. Expected signature base
>   string:"GET.."}